# how to place a character literal in a python string

Tags: python, regex, string-literals

I'm trying to write a regular expression in python, and one of the characters involved in it is the \001 character.  putting \001 in a string doesn't seem to work.  I also tried 'string' + str(chr(1)), but the regex doesn't seem to catch it.  Please for the love of god somebody help me, I've been struggling with this all day.

```
import sys
import postgresql
import re

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("usage: FixToDb <fix log file>")
else:
    f = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    timeExp = re.compile(r'(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d{6}) (\S)')
    tagExp = re.compile('(\\d+)=(\\S*)\001')
    for line in f:
        #parse the time
        m = timeExp.match(line)
        print(m.group(1) + ':' + m.group(2) + ':' + m.group(3) + '.' + m.group(4) + ' ' + m.group(5));
        tagPairs = re.findall('\\d+=\\S*\001', line)
        for t in tagPairs:
            tagPairMatch = tagExp.match(t)
            print ("tag = " + tagPairMatch.group(1) + ", value = " + tagPairMatch.group(2))
```

Here's is an example line of for the input.  I replaced the '\001' character with a '~' for readability

15:32:36.357227 R 1 0 0 0 8=FIX.4.2~9=0067~35=A~52=20120713-19:32:36~34=1~49=PD~56=P~98=0~108=30~10=134

output:

15:32:36.357227 R
tag = 8, value = FIX.4.29=006735=A52=20120713-19:32:3634=149=PD56=P98=0108=3010=134

So it doesn't stop at the '\001' character.

Comment: You should be using "raw" strings for re's...

Comment: In `timeExp`, wouldn't it be easier to capture the whole time expression in one set of parentheses so you don't have to rebuild the time expression (`print(m.group(1) + ':' ...`)?

Comment: @Jon Clements:  I think Alex is not using raw strings because he wants to include string literals in his pattern.  @Alex, If you are going avoid raw string in order to use string literals in the pattern backslashes should be doubled (`'\\'`).

Comment: Please say what the error is that your regular expression gives, or what it does that you don't want it to do.

Comment: @Sam Mussmann: well i plan on putting this stuff in a database and it'll be necessary to split up the values to construct the timestamp object

Comment: @BrenBarn the date stuff parses fine, but the tags will not get matched, probably because of the '\001' character.  so the timestamp gets printed fine, but the tagPairs object never has any matches

Comment: Please provide an *example* showing what input you provide, what output you get, and what output you want instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chr(1)` should work, as will `"\x01"`, as will `"\001"`.  (Note that `chr(1)` already returns a string, so you don't need to do `str(chr(1))`.)  In your example it looks like you have *both* `"\001"` *and* `chr(1)`, so that won't work unless you have two of the characters in a row in your data.

You say the regex "doesn't seem to catch it", but you don't give an example of your input data, so it's impossible to say why.

Edit; Okay, it looks like the problem has nothing to do with the `\001`.  It is the classic greediness problem.  The `\S*` in your tagExp expression will match a `\001` character (since that character is not whitespace.  So the `\S*` is gobbling the entire line.  Use `\S*?` to make it non-greedy.

Edit: As others have noted, it also looks like your backslashes are awry.  In regular expressions you face a backslash-doubling problem: Python uses the backslash for its own string escapes (like `\t` for tab, `\n` for newline), but regular expressions also use the backslash for their own purposes (e.g., `\s` for whitespace).  The usual solution is to use raw strings, but you can't do that if you want to use the `"\001"` escape.  However, you could use raw strings for your `timeExp` regex.  Then in your other regexes, double the backslashes (except on `\001`, because you want that one to be interpreted as a character-code escape).

Comment: sorry, i didn't mean to have both \001 and str(chr(1)), that was a typo in the post.  And i threw an example up there, it is all one line.

Comment: @Alex: See my edited answer.  The problem has nothing to do with `\001`, it is because the greedy matching of the `\S*` expression consumes the whole line before reaching a `\001`.

Comment: Ok, I removed the double back slashes and added the '?' after the \S* and it seems to work fine.  Thank you very much, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `\S` to match the value, which can be any non-whitespace character, including `\001`, you should use `[^\x01]`, which will match any character that is not `\001`.

Answer (score 0):

@Sam Mussmann, no...

`1` (decimal) **=** `\001` (octal) **<>** `\x01` (UNICODE)